# Installing Technic Launcher

Tags: software-installation

I have a question about installing some software. The main problem is that is doesn't have any suffix (.jar/.exe/...). Its entire name is **Technic_Launcher_64bit**. Do you have any suggestion on how to use that kind of software? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What is Technic_Launcher_64bit? From where it was downloaded? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: To @N0rbert [Technic Launcher](https://www.technicpack.net/download) is a 3rd-party Minecraft Launcher (as an alternative to the default one). To the OP, the official download for the Technic Launcher ([from the official website](https://www.technicpack.net/download)) is named `TechnicLauncher.jar`, which you would run with `java -jar ./TechnicLauncher.jar`. If your filename is different you either (a) got it from somewhere else (probobly somewhere suspicious, I suggest deleting it) or (b) you renamed it. In the case of (a), delete your download and re-download from the official website.